# Text input doesnt work inside Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I have the following HTML to open a popup. Here the button works fine. It is clickable, but not an input. The text input seems to have a hidden `disabled=true`, but it's not.

What could be the problem?

```js
const pop = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100"
  data-bs-toggle="popover"
  data-bs-offset="0,14"
  data-bs-placement="top"
  data-bs-html="true"
  data-bs-content="<div class='input-group-sm'>
  <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='https://...'/>
  <button class='btn btn-primary'>Save</button></div>"
>
    
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: your input field may be in an element that has the `readonly` attribute set. If this is the case, you can remove the `readonly` attribute from the element to make the input field editable.

Comment: "By default, this component uses the built-in content sanitizer, which strips out any HTML elements that are not explicitly allowed. See the [sanitizer section in our JavaScript documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#sanitizer) for more details."  ~[docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/popovers/#overview)

Comment: I would argue that a modal dialog is a better UX here anyway. Popovers aren't intended for interaction.

Comment: This issue on GitHub helped me https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22249